# Estimating regularity of sheaves with rank of certain modules and zeroth cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I'm studying Eisenbud's book "Geometry of syzygies", in particular the Gruson-Lazarsfeld-Peskine theorem for Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity.
I'm concerned about an intermediate step in the proof. Let us recall that a linear presentation for a graded finitely generated module $M$ over a polynomial ring $R$ is an exact sequence of the form
$$R(-1)^n\longrightarrow R^m\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow 0$$
Now, let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf; there's a result (Theorem 5.5) stating that $M=\bigoplus_n H^0(\mathcal F{n})$ has a linear presentation if
$$H^1(\wedge^2\mathcal{M}\otimes \mathcal{F})=0$$
where $\mathcal{M}$ is the tautological $r$-sub-bundle, that is the sheaf making exact the Euler sequence:
$$0\longrightarrow \mathcal{M}\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^r}^{r+1}\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^r}(1)\longrightarrow 0$$
namely, the cotangent sheaf. 
I'm in trouble understanding the proof of the following theorem. You can strengthen hypotheses by assuming that $\mathcal F$ is a locally free sheaf (in every point).
[image]

Corollary 5.9 is the following:
[image]

Using Corollary, the only thing I can say is $\mathrm{reg}(\mathscr{I}_h(\varphi))\leq h$ holds (then there's an inequality with the ideal sheaf, but it's not a trouble). I can't figure out why should $\mathrm{reg}(\mathscr{I}_h(\varphi))\leq h^0(\mathcal{F})$ hold; the only idea was to prove that $h^0(\mathcal{F})\geq h$, but this is clearly false in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a coherent sheaf $\mathcal F$ (over a variety $X$ over a field $k$) is globally generated, it is certainly globally generated by a basis of $H^0(X,\mathcal F)$. Hence you can choose $h \leq h^0 (\mathcal F)$.

Comment: Thank you, now I see it better. Basically, you are saying that when picking a minimal presentation for $\mathcal F$ one has automatically that inequality.